# Optimization C++ code to match reference run time

Tags: c++

I have assigment to optimize some c++ code, I'm bad at coding but I made some attempts so the original is:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "HistogramStretching.h"



void CHistogramStretching::HistogramStretching(BYTE** pImage, int nW, int nH)
{
    //find minimal value
    int nMin = pImage[0][0];
    for(int j = 0; j < nW; j++)
        for(int i = 0; i < nH; i++)
            if(pImage[i][j] < nMin)
                nMin = pImage[i][j];

    //find maximal value
    int nMax = pImage[0][0];
    for(int j = 0; j < nW; j++)
        for(int i = 0; i < nH; i++)
            if(pImage[i][j] > nMax)
                nMax = pImage[i][j];

    //stretches histogram
    for(int j = 0; j < nW; j++)
        for(int i = 0; i < nH; i++)
        {
            if(nMax != nMin)
            {
                float fScale = (nMax - nMin)/100.0;//calculates scale
                float fVal = (pImage[i][j] - nMin)/fScale;//scales pixel value
                int nVal = (int)(fVal + 0.5);//rounds floating point number to integer

                //checks BYTE range (must be 0-255)
                if(nVal < 0)
                    nVal = 0;
                if(nVal > 255)
                    nVal = 255;

                pImage[i][j] = nVal;
            }
            else
                pImage[i][j] = 0;//if all pixel values are the same, the image is changed to black
        }

}
```

And my verison is:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "HistogramStretching.h"

void CHistogramStretching::HistogramStretching(BYTE** pImage, int nW, int nH)
{
    //find minimal value
    int nMin = pImage[0][0];
    int nMax = pImage[0][0];
    for (int j = 0; j < nW; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nH; i++) {
            if (pImage[i][j] < nMin)
                nMin = pImage[i][j];
            if (pImage[i][j] > nMax)
                nMax = pImage[i][j];

        }
    }

    if (nMax != nMin) {
        float fScale = (nMax - nMin) / 100.0;//calculates scale
        fScale = 1 / fScale;
        //stretches histogram
        for (int j = 0; j < nW; j++)
            for (int i = 0; i < nH; i++)
            {


                float fVal = (pImage[i][j] - nMin) * fScale;//scales pixel value
                int nVal = (int)(fVal + 0.5);//rounds floating point number to integer

                //checks BYTE range (must be 0-255)
                if (nVal < 0)
                    nVal = 0;
                if (nVal > 255)
                    nVal = 255;

                pImage[i][j] = nVal;
            }
        //if all pixel values are the same, the image is changed to black

    }
    else {
        pImage[0][0] = 0;

    }
}
```

So I merged the first two loops to one but still the first if make ~15% CPU time, next step was to pull the if statement outside the loops and changing division for multiplication and here that division takes ~8% of CPU time and float to int casting takes ~5% but I think I can't do much with casting. With this "correcions" my code is still some like 6-7 times slower than refference code. I test both code on the same machines. Can you point me to something I can make better?

Comment: Are you running the release build? I have seen cases where a release executable took a few minutes to process and the debug build took several days on the same data.

Comment: Loops within loops all over the place? Better check that your code is being optimized aggressively, and if not, look at vectorizing it where you can. You're also iterating in the order of j,i which may be inefficient as your structure is laid out i,j, so it could confuse the prefetch unit.

Comment: Dreschrejm I cant build it in release mode because Visual studio keeps spiting error MSB8041 I installed  like all C++ x64 MFC libraries and still this error, but I will look to it closer then. Tadman I'm using visual studio and optymalization is set to max optimization prefer speed /O2, but can you talk some more on vectorizing? Because I don't have any idea what it is.

Comment: There are two divisions required to calculate fScale. Could do it one of you swapped the operands around i.e. 100/(nMax-nMin).

Comment: @castro I don't really understand what you did there. Isn't it like 2/4? 2/4=1/2 but 4/2 = 2. Correct me if I'm wrong but I just don't understan that.

Comment: float fScale = (nMax - nMin) / 100.0; 
fScale = 1 / fScale; ----> Is the same as ----> float fScale = 100.0 / (nMax - nMin); Saying that, the compiler probably would have optimised this anyway. Best to try building in release.

Comment: Ohh like this sure, of course you are right! Thank you. And I manage to build it in release and now it is only like 4 times slower so almost there!

Comment: *Until you manage to produce a proper release build, all hope is lost.* Get the build working first. Modern C++ compilers are good at figuring these loops out. They may rearrange and unroll the inner loop.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica Yes I did it! I manage to build it in release mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All modern compilers can vectorize this nicely, when compiled at full optimization (/O2 for MSVC, -O3 for gcc and clang).

The idea is to give the compiler some help so that it can see that the code can be in fact vectorized:

1. Let the inner loop operate on a single pointer, not on indices, and without accessing anything but the pointed-to value.
2. Perform the scaling as an integer operation - and don't forget rounding :)
3. Try to set up operations such that additional range checks are unnecessary, e.g. your checks for `BYTE` being less than 0. By having the offset and scale set up properly, the result will be guaranteed to fall into the desired range.

The inner loops will get unrolled, and will be vectorized to process 4 bytes at a time. I've tried the recent gcc, clang and MSVC releases and they produce pretty fast code for this.

You're doing something "weird" in that you purposefully scale the results to a 0-99 range. Thus you lose the resolution of the data - you've got a full byte to work with, so why not scale it to 255?

But if you want to scale to 100 values, it's fine. Note that 100(dec) = 0x64. We can make the `outputSpan` flexible - it will work for any value <= 255.

Thus:

```
/* Code Part 1 */
#include <cstdint>

constexpr uint32_t outputSpan = 100;

static constexpr uint32_t scale_16(uint8_t min, uint8_t max)
{
    return (outputSpan * 0x10000) / (1+max-min);
}
// scale factor in 16.16 fixed point unsigned format
// empty histogram produces scale = outputSpan
static_assert(scale_16(10, 10) == outputSpan * 0x10000, "Scale calculation is wrong");

static constexpr uint8_t scale_pixel(uint8_t const pixel, uint8_t min, uint32_t const scale)
{
    uint32_t px  = (pixel - min) * scale;
    // result in 16.16 fixed point format
    return (px + 0x8080u) >> 16;
    // round to an integer value
}
```

We work with fixed-point numbers (instead of floating-point). The scale is in 16.16 format, thus 16 digits in the integer part, and 16 digits in the fractional part, e.g. 0x1234.5678. The value 1.0(dec) would be 0x1.0000.

The pixel scaling simply multiplies the pixel by the scale, rounds it, and returns the truncated integer part.

The rounding is "interesting". You'd think that it'd suffice to add 0.5(dec) = 0x0.8 to the result to round it. That's not the case. The value needs to be a bit larger than that, and 0x0.808 does the job. It pre-biases the value, so that the error range around the exact value has a zero mean. In all cases, the error is at most ±0.5 - thus the result, rounded to an integer, does not lose accuracy.

We use `scale_16` and `scale_pixel` functions to implement the stretcher:

```
/* Code Part 2 */
void stretchHistogram(uint8_t **pImage, int const nW, int const nH)
{
    uint8_t nMin = 255, nMax = 0;

    for (uint8_t **row = pImage, **rowEnd = pImage + nH; row != rowEnd; ++row)
        for (const uint8_t *p = *row, *pEnd = p + nW; p != pEnd; ++p)
        {
            auto const px = *p;
            if (px < nMin) nMin = px;
            if (px > nMax) nMax = px;
        }

    auto const scale = scale_16(nMin, nMax);

    for (uint8_t **row = pImage, **rowEnd = pImage + nH; row != rowEnd; ++row)
        for (uint8_t *p = *row, *pEnd = p + nW; p != pEnd; ++p)
            *p = scale_pixel(*p, nMin, scale);
}
```

This also produces decent code on architectures without FPU, such as FPU-less ARM and AVR.

We can also do some manual checks. Suppose that `min = 0x10`, `max = 0xEF`, and `pixel = 0x32`. Let's remember that the `scale` is in 16.16 format:

```
scale = 0x64.0000 / (1 + max - min)
      = 0x64.0000 / (1 + 0xEF - 0x10)
      = 0x64.0000 / (1 + 0xDF)
      = 0x64.0000 / 0xE0
```

Long division:

```
       0x  .7249
       0x64.0000 / 0xE0
       ---------
         64.0
       - 62.0
       ------
          2.00
       -  1.C0
       -------
           .400
       -   .380
       --------
           . 800
       -   . 7E0
       ---------
           .  20
```

So, we have `scale = 0x0.7249`. It's less than one (0x1.0), and also a bit less than 1/2 (0x0.8), since we map 224 values onto 100 values - a bit less than half as many.

Now

```
px = (pixel - min) * scale 
   = (0x32 - 0x10) * 0x0.7249
   =  0x22 * 0x0.7249
```

Long multiplication:

```
   0x 0.7249
*  0x  .0022
------------
       .E492
+     E.492
------------
   0x F.2DB2
```

Thus, `px = 0xF.2DB2 ≈ 0xF`. We have to round it to an integer:

```
return = (px + 0x0.8080u) >> 16
       = (0xF.2DB2 + 0x0.8080) >> 16
       =  0xF.AE32 >> 16
       ≈  0xF
```

Let's check in decimal system:

```
100 / (max-min+1) * (pixel-min) =
                                = 100 / (239 - 16 + 1) * (50 - 16)
                                = 100 / 224 * 34
                                = 100 * 34 / 224
                                = 3400 / 224
                                ≈ 15.17 
                                ≈ 15
                                ≈ 0xF
```

Here's a test case that ensures that there's no rounding bias for all combinations of `min`, `max`, and input pixel value, and that the error is bounded to [-0.5, 0.5]. Just append it to the code above and it should compile and run and produce the following output:

```
-0.5 0.5 1
```

For scaling to `outputSpan = 256` values (instead of 100), it'd output:

```
-0.498039 0.498039 0.996078
```

```
/* Code Part 3 */

#include <cassert>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double errMin = 0, errMax = 0;

    for (uint16_t min = 0; min <= 255; ++min)
        for (uint16_t max = min; max <= 255; ++max)
            for (uint16_t val = min; val <= max; ++val)
        {
            uint8_t const nMin = min, nMax = max;
            uint8_t const span = nMax - nMin;
            uint8_t const val_src = val;
            uint8_t p_val = val_src;
            uint8_t *const p = &p_val;
            assert(nMin <= nMax);
            assert(val >= nMin && val <= nMax);

            auto const scale = scale_16(nMin, nMax);
            *p = scale_pixel(*p, nMin, scale);

            auto pValTarget = (val_src - nMin) * 256.0/(1.0+span);
            auto error = pValTarget - *p;
            if (error < errMin) errMin = error;
            if (error > errMax) errMax = error;
        }

    std::cout << '\n' << errMin << ' ' << errMax << ' ' << errMax-errMin << std::endl;
    assert((errMax-errMin) <= 1.0); // constrain the error
    assert(std::abs(errMax+errMin) == 0.0); // constrain the error average
}
```

Comment: As this probably runs like crazy, it is too much for me to understand and cant manage to get correct results with this code.

Comment: I didn't notice that you were scaling to an output between 0-99, I thought it was 0-255. Frankly said, 100 makes little sense (you lose data), but it's fine either way. I've added some arithmetic examples to demonstrate how fixed point arithmetic works. You've learned it in school a million times and you know exactly how it works, you just perhaps never have done it in hexadecimal :)

Comment: Wow, thank you very much and yes I never have done fixed point arithmetic in hex. Now I get most of it. Very good explanation, again thank you for so in detail explanation.

Comment: Nie ma sprawy :) Cieszę się, że się przydało.

Answer (score 2):

I think tadman gave you the correct answer. 
Replace

```
for (int j = 0; j < nW; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nH; i++) {
        if (pImage[i][j] < nMin)
        ...
    }
}
```

with

```
for (int i = 0; i < nH; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < nW; j++) {
        if (pImage[i][j] < nMin)
        ...
    }
}
```

This way your data access becomes cache/memory aligned, which should be way faster.

Comment: Ohh, now I see it. I would have never thought this can speed this.